# best practice for a function which interacts with a database

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Say I have a `User` object, which is generated by a `Usermapper`. The `User` object does not know anything about the database/repository in use (which I believe to be good design).

When creating a `User`, I only want it to have it filled by the mapper with the most trivial things e.g. Name, address etc. However after object instantiation I might have a method `userX.getTotalDebt()`, `getTotalDebt()` would need to reconnect to the database , because I don't want this relatively expensive operation to be done for every User instantiation (multiple tables needed etc). If I'd simply insert some sql in the `getTotalDebt()` or a dependency back to the `Mapper` where the coupledness is growing tight very fast.

There is an obvious good/best practice for this, because it's a situation arises often, however I can't find it or I'm looking at this problem totally from a wrong angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say I have a User object, which is generated by a Usermapper. The User object does not know anything about the database/repository in use (which I believe to be good design).

They are often referred to as POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects).

> When creating a User I only want it to have it filled by the mapper with the most trivial things e.g. Name, address etc.

There are several OR/M layers which can achieve this. Use either nhibernate or Entity Framework 4.1 Code First.

> I might have a method userX.getTotalDebt(), getTotalDebt() would need to reconnect to the database

Then it's not a poco anymore. Although it is possible using a transparent proxy. Both EF and nhibernate supports this and it's called Lazy Loading.

> There is an obvious good/best practice for this, because it's a situation arises often, however I can't find it or I'm looking at this problem totally from a wrong angle

I usually keep my objects dumb and disconnected. I use the Repository pattern (even if I use nhibernate or another orm) since it makes my classes testable.

I either use the repository classes directly or create a service class which contains all logic. It depends on how complex my application is.

Comment: Then where would you/ORM have implemented the functionality for the getTotalDebt() method? At instantation in the Mapper, concretely -- by joining a lot more tables in the database? Because I read between the lines that you too dislike the transparent proxy/Lazy loading method.

Comment: Lazy loading moves database exceptions outside the data layer and can generate a lot of SQL queries if you are not careful. It's better to do a join and return a complete list.

Comment: Thank you for your insights so far. I was quite content with the join-solution so far. However, this is becoming pretty tedious  joining different tables on and on. Already I'm starting to use groupby clauses which are slowing down object creation.

Comment: --follow-up
I was thinking about the following,let the controller figure out when it's time retrieve corresponding info, eg. I have retrieved an array of users.Then I could call something in the trend of: `userDataMapper.retrieveTurnOver($users)` and this method would change the User.turnover field from null to the actual value.
does this make sense,design wise?